# Динамически добавить элемент html по нажатии на кнопку

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Здравствуйте. Есть простая html форма. Я хочу, чтобы по нажатии на кнопку "отправить" в эту форму добавлялся еще один элемент "chat self". Как это можно сделать? Я только-только начал это изучать. Буду благодарен любым ссылкам

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>ПростоЧат</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
 <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>

 <div class="chatWindow">
  <div class="chatLog">
  
   <div class="chat friend">
    <p class="message-time">11:42</p>
    <p class="name">#1</p>
    <p class="chat-message">Сообщение #1</p>
   </div>
   
   <div class="chat self">
    <p class="message-time">11:43</p>
    <p class="name">#2</p>
    <p class="chat-message">Сообщение #2</p>
   </div>
   
   <div class="chat friend">
    <p class="message-time">11:45</p>
    <p class="name">#1</p>
    <p class="chat-message">Сообщение #3</p>
   </div>
   
   <div class="chat self">
    <p class="message-time">11:47</p>
    <p class="name">#2</p>
    <p class="chat-message">Сообщение #4</p>
   </div>
   

  </div>
  
  <div class="chat-form">
   <textarea></textarea>
   <button>Отправить</button>
  </div>
  
 </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если вам просто надо скопировать `DIV` можете использовать `clone`

Однако мне кажется что вам нужно не просто копировать уже существующий `DIV` а создать и заполнить информацией, новый `DIV`

```
var time = '/* вставляете реальное время (через js) */ ';
var name = '/* вставляете имя коментатора */ ';
var count = '/* вставляете порядковый номер комментария */ ';

var html = '<div class="chat self"><p class="message-time">'+time+'</p><p class="name">'+name+'</p><p class="chat-message">Сообщение #'+count+'</p></div>';
    $('.chatLog').append(html);
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Очень помогли

Comment: Пожалуйста, рад помочь!   )

Comment: первый вариант работает ошибочно, его лучше совсем убрать и оставить только второй

Comment: @Grundy а что в первой версии работает ошибочно ? могу убрать конечно первую версию, но код же работает ?

Comment: @Arsen, ты посмотри что именно добавляешь

Comment: @Grundy, если честно, я так и не понял в чём проблема была, код нормально работал,  однако я удалили первую версию, т.к для исполнителя в любом случае необходимо сделать вторую версию ответа )))

Comment: @Arsen, в том, что новые элементы добавлялись **во все** существующие

Comment: @Grundy     аааа ))) заметил )

Comment: @Arsen этим способом `div` будет добавляться снизу списка - а как сделать, чтобы он добавлялся в самый верх?

Comment: @PeterSamokhin для этого используйте prepend,  $('.chatLog').prepend(html);

Answer (score 1):

Я так ради собственной треннировки заморочился и наКодил вот такой сценарий.
НеОбесСудьте ;-)

```js
function appElem() {
  var appDiv = document.createElement('div'); //добавляем div
  elemP = document.createElement("p");
  elemP2 = document.createElement("p");
  elemP3 = document.createElement("p");
  putDiv = document.querySelector('[class="chatLog"]');
  putDiv.appendChild(appDiv);
  appDiv.setAttribute('class', 'chat self');
  putElemP = document.querySelector('[class="chat self"]:last-child');
  putElemP.appendChild(elemP);
  elemP.setAttribute('class', 'message-time');
  elemP.innerHTML = "your time";
  putElemP.appendChild(elemP2);
  elemP2.setAttribute('class', 'name');
  elemP2.innerHTML = "your name";
  putElemP.appendChild(elemP3);
  elemP3.setAttribute('class', 'chat-message');
  elemP3.innerHTML = "your message";
}
```

```html
<div class="chatWindow">
  <div class="chatLog">

    <div class="chat friend">
      <p class="message-time">11:42</p>
      <p class="name">#1</p>
      <p class="chat-message">Сообщение #1</p>
    </div>

    <div class="chat self">
      <p class="message-time">11:43</p>
      <p class="name">#2</p>
      <p class="chat-message">Сообщение #2</p>
    </div>

    <div class="chat friend">
      <p class="message-time">11:45</p>
      <p class="name">#1</p>
      <p class="chat-message">Сообщение #3</p>
    </div>

    <div class="chat self">
      <p class="message-time">11:47</p>
      <p class="name">#2</p>
      <p class="chat-message">Сообщение #4</p>
    </div>


  </div>

  <div class="chat-form">
    <textarea></textarea>
    <button onclick="appElem()">Отправить</button>
  </div>

</div>
```